# Valgrind on bash for Windows 10

Tags: c++, bash, windows-10

I manage to install valgrind on bash for Win10 by compiling the package from the official site but I got this problem

```
char string[10000];
```

When I compile and run it, it's okay, it works just fine but whenever I use valgrind it crashed by saying

> Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
>
> General Protection Fault at 0x400568: main (test.cpp:7)

I guess it's somehow connected with stack and my question is how to fix this problem and if it's a stack problem how to increase the stack size value (ulimit says unlimited). Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please attach your code.

Comment: @Danra the code is only this line, I was just testing it.

Comment: @Aserre oh damn, I didnt find this thread. Thanks a lot. Yeah it is a duplicate of that problem.

Comment: No problem. And unfortunatly for you, the gitHub link provided in the answer shows several bug reports for Valgrind, but no bugfix anounced so far.